# What is hapenning at process level while viewing huge size of file?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I observered a behavior that i have a file of 1.2GB [ debug file], which i tried opening in VI editor. The machine was drastically slow. Could someone give explanation of system level why it is being very slow?

Comment: Why "at system level"? There are editors which do *not* suffer from slowdown with large files. There are also editors which slow down on small files (i.e. smaller than your gigafile). Therefore, one can conclude it has nothing to do with the "system".

Answer (score 3):

Maybe because Vi isn´t suited for such large files? It probably tries to load the whole file in RAM, maybe this trigger swap usage, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can run **top** command in parallel window and check the utilization of the Virtual Memory and Shared Memory.